# Calculate Disparity

Tags: java, opencv, stereo-3d, vision

I am using **OpenCV** with **Java** and I am very new to Image Processing and Computer Vision.

I have facial images from a Stereo Camera, along with Camera Matrices, and rotation matrices for each camera.

How can I calculate Disparity Map? The StereoSBGM compute function requires rectified images, so how should I rectify images using the above camera information.

EDIT 1 : The Following is the source of Images : 
http://cvlab.epfl.ch/data/stereoface

I first converted the images to grayscale, detected faces in the images using lbpcascade, then with goodFeaturesToTrack I got relevent points on the face. Next I need disparity of these points, so after searching I found StereoSGBM compute function. However it requires rectified images. For rectification of images everyone points to stereoRectify function which outputs Rotation and projection matrices for each camera, but I have no idea how to apply these to the images and I also already have rotation matrices for each camera, so I think I do not really need the stereoRectify function.

The question remains how to apply rotation matrix to an image so as to rectify it.

Comment: would be great to have more technical details on that, what did you try so far

Comment: http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/stereo-calibration/ <- provides a pretty good walkthrough of all the required steps.